# Decorator for setting up bracketing rootfinding functions

Tags: python, design-patterns, numerical-methods

I'm looking for comments on the use of decorators for the following problem (validating initial guesses for bracketing rootfinding methods), as well as any other comments you might have on the design below.

```
def bracketing(rootfinder):
    def wrapper(func, x0, x1, *args, **kwargs):
        func_x0, func_x1 = func(x0), func(x1)

        if func_x0 * func_x1 > 0.0:
            return None

        return rootfinder(func, x0, x1, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper


@bracketing
def bisection(func, x0, x1, max_iterations, tolerance):
    if x1 < x0:
        x0, x1 = x1, x0

    func_x0 = func(x0)

    for _ in range(max_iterations):
        x_mid = 0.5 * (x0 + x1)
        func_x_mid = func(x_mid)

        if func_x0 * func_x_mid > 0.0:
            x0 = x_mid
            func_x0 = func_x_mid
        else:
            x1 = x_mid

        if x1 - x0 < tolerance:
            return x_mid

    return None


@bracketing
def false_position(func, x0, x1, max_iterations, tolerance):
    func_x0, func_x1 = func(x0), func(x1)

    for _ in range(max_iterations):
        x2 = (x0 * func_x1 - x1 * func_x0) / (func_x1 - func_x0)
        func_x2 = func(x2)

        if func_x0 * func_x2 > 0.0:
            x0, func_x0 = x2, func_x2
        else:
            x1, func_x1 = x2, func_x2

        if abs(func_x2) < tolerance:
            return x2

    return None
```